# Passing value from detailsview to gridview

Tags: c#, gridview, detailsview

I have 2 gridview and detailsview, retrieving using objectdatasource.

When i select GridView1, it will display its details in GridView2 and a DetailsView which visible is false. The value inside the detailsview would be pass to gridview. However, now thevalue was unable to pass into the gridview. The system would always execute GridView2_RowDataBound first before going into detailsview date bound.

Here is the code:

```
   <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" 
            runat="server" 
            Height="19px" 
            Width="154px" 
            AppendDataBoundItems="True" 
            AutoPostBack="True" 
            DataTextField="invoiceStatus" 
            DataValueField="invoiceStatus" 
            DataSourceID="getStatus" >

</asp:DropDownList> 


&nbsp;<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="getStatus" runat="server" SelectMethod="getStatus" 
    TypeName="iWineBlInvoice">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="poNum" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="invoiceNum" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="invoiceStatus" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters> 

</asp:ObjectDataSource>
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" 
    SelectMethod="getInvoice" TypeName="iWineBlInvoice" FilterExpression="[invoiceStatus]='{0}'" >
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="invoiceNum" Type="Int32" />

    </SelectParameters>

</asp:ObjectDataSource>
<br />
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1" 
    onrowdatabound="GridViewInvoice_RowDataBound" 
    onselectedindexchanged="GridViewInvoice_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />

        <asp:BoundField DataField="invoiceNum" HeaderText="Invoice No" 
            SortExpression="invoiceNum" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="supplierName" HeaderText="Supplier " 
            SortExpression="supplierName" />
        <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="certifyGood" HeaderText="Goods Received" 
        SortExpression="certifyGood"  />

    </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>


  <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource3" runat="server" 
    SelectMethod="getDetails" TypeName="iWineBlInvoice">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="supplierLogo" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="supplierName" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="supplierAddr" Type="String" />
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="GridViewInvoice" Name="poNum" 
            PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="invoiceNum" Type="Int32" />

    </SelectParameters>
    </asp:ObjectDataSource>

       <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource3" 
    DataKeyNames="poNum" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="16px" 
    style="text-align: center" Width="696px" 
     onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound" >
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="poNum" HeaderText="Purchase Order No" 
            SortExpression="poNum" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="invoiceDate" HeaderText="Invoice Date" 
            SortExpression="invoiceDate" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="invoiceDueDate" HeaderText="Invoice Due Date" 
            SortExpression="invoiceDueDate" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="deliveryDate" HeaderText="Delivery Date " 
            SortExpression="deliveryDate" />

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Payment Date " SortExpression="datePaid">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="paymentDate" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>

        </asp:TemplateField>

    </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>

    <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource2" runat="server" SelectMethod="getPayment" 
    TypeName="iWineBlInvoice">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="GridViewInvoice" Name="poNum" 
            PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="datePaid" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>

<br />

 <asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False" 
    DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource2" Height="50px" Width="125px" 
    ondatabound="DetailsView1_DataBound">
    <Fields>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="poNum" HeaderText="poNum" SortExpression="poNum" />

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="datePaid" SortExpression="datePaid">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="paymentDateLbl" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("datePaid") %>'>      </asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>

        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Fields>
    </asp:DetailsView>
```

Here is the code behind:

```
String payment2 = string.Empty; 

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

protected void DetailsView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Label payment = (Label)DetailsView1.FindControl("paymentDateLbl");
    if (payment != null)
    {
        payment2 = payment.Text; 

    }

}

protected void GridView2_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        Label aaa = new Label();
        aaa.Text = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text;

        if (aaa.Text == "Paid")
        {
            Label paymentDate = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("paymentDate");
            paymentDate.Text = payment2;  //payment 2 has become null 
        }

      } 
   }
```

Comment: What a strange way to check a string: `Label aaa = new Label();
        aaa.Text = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text; if (aaa.Text == "Paid"){...`. You just have to use this: `if(DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text == "Paid"){...`

Comment: You need to explain more about how data binding happens, it seems that a data row in GridView2 is bound to some data before the detailsView1 and we cannot tell anything unless we know how the interaction with the controls takes place

Comment: I have added in the code in aspx file.